# Sharing an image with a link in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to be able to share the screenshot of the app along with a link. I already know how to grab a screenshot and share it using ShareMediaTask. The problem is that ShareMediaTask does not allow the app to attach a link with the image. I want share target to get a link too. e.g, sharing an image and a link/text to facebook app. If someone knows how to do that just with fb/twitter, that'll also help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using ShareMediaTask or ShareLinkTask. You can do it using WinRT sharing API. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh738426.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.aspx) class in order to share links?

Reference: [How to share a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973056.aspx)

Or else you could go for the `ShareLinkTask` in order to achieve this:

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Reference: [How to use the share link task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394009(v=vs.105).aspx)!

Comment: But the question is how to share link and image at once. In your example you can share only link.

Comment: ShowShareUI() method of DataTransfer class says not supported on WP8.